# Golang Accessing Template Variables From Included Templates

Tags: go, go-templates

**In golang, I am working with three files:** index.html, nav.html and main.go

**nav.html contains the following:**

```
{{ define "nav" }}
  <nav class="nav-container">
    <h1>{{ .path }}</h1>
  </nav>
{{ end }}
```

**index.html contains the following:**

```
{{ define "index" }}
  {{ template "nav" }} <!-- Includes the nav.html file -->

  <h1>Welcome to my website. You are visiting {{ .path }}.</h1>
{{ end }}
```

I am using Golang's [template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) package along with [Martini](https://github.com/go-martini/martini) which is not too important in this case.

**My main.go file contains:**

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/go-martini/martini"
    "github.com/martini-contrib/render"
)

func main() {
    m := martiniSetup()

    m.Get("/", func(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, ren render.Render, params martini.Params) {
        parse := make(map[string]interface{})
        parse["path"] = req.URL.Path

        ren.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index", parse)
    })

    m.Run()
}
```

---

**My problem:**

The `.path` variable being parsed into the `index` template is only accessable by the `index` template itself.

I include the `nav` template using `{{ template "nav" }}` inside `index.html`. The issue is, `nav.html` cannot access the .path variable. It is only accessable by the index template.

Is there any way to make the `.path` variable accessable to all included template files, in my case `index.html` and `nav.html`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the data to the nested template as an argument like this: `{{ template "nav" . }}`
Now the dot will be accessible within the `define "nav"` block.

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked! :)